I can't verify contract code deployed on ZKsync with Foundry
I have a contract that I deployed on ZKsync. It deployed successfully, but I can't verify the code so I can see it on zksync block explorer:
Look at this command
forge verify-contract \
    --zksync \
    --num-of-optimizations 200 \
    --watch \
    --constructor-args $(cast abi-encode "constructor(string)" "MY_CONSTRUCTOR_PARAMETER") \
    --etherscan-api-key https://zksync2-mainnet-explorer.zksync.io/contract_verification \
    --compiler-version v0.8.19 \
    MY_CONTRACTS_DEPLOYED_ADDRESS \
    src/MY_CONTRACT_NAME.sol:MY_CONTRACT_NAME

This command results in an Invalid API Key error. Which is expected because I put https://zksync2-mainnet-explorer.zksync.io/contract_verification for --etherscan-api-key. The problem is that I can't see a way to login on https://explorer.zksync.io/ like I can on Etherscan, so I can't get an API key.
Before you tell me about https://explorer.zksync.io/contracts/verify?address=MY_CONTRACT_NAME, this doesn't work for me. I filled out the form exactly correct. I attached my flattened code which I made by running:
forge flatten src/MY_CONTRACT_NAME.sol > MY_CONTRACT_NAMEFlattened.sol

And filled out every other detail correctly including the constructor arguments which I got with cast abi-encode "constructor(string)" "MY_CONSTRUCTOR_PARAMETER", but it gives me a Deployed bytecode is not equal to generated one from given source error which makes no sense because I filled it out perfectly.
So can someone show me how to verify the deployed contract via Foundry?
